# How to reset initialized jQuery plugin variables on some other event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, pagination

I am having trouble to initialize twbs-pagination jQuery plugin. In document.ready section it works fine but if i need to reset or re-initialize plugin variable in a function (after document loaded) or button click event it gives **not a function** error. Here is my code

This works fine

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {    
    $('#paging-cont').twbsPagination({
        visiblePages: 7,
        totalPages: 12,
    });
});
```

problem is when i am trying to initialize plugin after document.ready

```
function ShowPagger(totalRec) {
    $('#paging-cont').twbsPagination({
        visiblePages: 7,
        totalPages: totalRec,
    });
}
```

this give error of **not a function**

Comment: here this guy is trying to do the same thing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961833/reset-total-pages-in-jquery-pagination-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a workaround for similar issue. Checkout the answer here:

[Reset total pages in jquery pagination plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961833/reset-total-pages-in-jquery-pagination-plugin)

The essential idea behind this is to reconstruct the pagination control each time. For this I am using a container, clearing and filling each time when I receive the `data`

```
$('#paginationholder').html('');
$('#paginationholder').html('<ul id="pagination" class="pagination-sm"></ul>');
$('#pagination').twbsPagination({
    startPage: data.page,
    totalPages: data.total,
    visiblePages: 5,
});
```

Comment: @KrishnaSarma thanks for fast reply.I tried to empty and create html every time as you have mentioned but still same error.

Comment: Can you share some more codes relevant to the situation? Probably if the function is defined in different scope (like inside jq ready) and trying to access it from outside, this could happen.

Answer (score 1):

First I'm sending ajax request and retrieve totalPages, visiblePages and startPage.
Then:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

$('#pagination-for-posts-bottom').twbsPagination({
    totalPages: totalPostPages,
    visiblePages: visiblePostPages,
    startPage: currentPage,
    onPageClick: function (event, page) {
        console.log("document.ready: " + totalPostPages);
        console.log("document.ready current page: " + page);
        offset = (page - 1) * 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

A typo

--> fucntion  should be

```
function ShowPagger(totalRec) {
    $('#paging-cont').twbsPagination({
        visiblePages: 7,
        totalPages: totalRec // remove , from here
    });
}
```

and remove that trailing `,` after total pages in function.

```
$('#paging-cont').twbsPagination({
    visiblePages: 7,
    totalPages: 12 // remove , from here
});
```

Comment: That's a typing mistake over here. Its fine in code.

Comment: @PraveenRawat Updated answer as well